# how to escape special characters in a path PHP

Tags: php, special-characters

I checked the internet and stackoverflow for a reliable answer but to no avail.
My question is this =>
Consider the following path name

```
D:\folder1\folder2\filli.pgn
```

or

```
D:\folder1\folder2\roklu.pgn
```

Now the \f and the \r  here cause problems and give rise to errors. There are many special characters in PHP beside these. How can I escape all of them. Surely there must be a way...
Thank you

Comment: if this is common `D:\folder1\folder2\` then define it as a variable and then directly use keyword after it

Comment: Hello @Ms.Nehal, In the long term the path  will be selected by the user by the upload facility of HTML. But for now since I am at the development stage I need the code to work without hinderance. Concatanating the variable with the string gives the same result. The characters must be escaped.... Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape the slash by putting a slash before it. This will prevent the next character from being treated as part of an escape sequence. e.g.

```
D:\\folder1\\folder2\\roklu.pgn
```

Comment: Hi @Chris...I'll chose your answer if you answer this question. If I chose the files manually with the upload facility of HTML will I encounter the same problem?

Comment: @Otag No, if the file path is already in a variable (for example `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]`) it doesn't need any extra escaping because escape characters are only processed when using string literals.